# Is there a TPL (Async/Await) based socket abstraction?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a TCP client to communicate with a server. Looking at code samples (Socket, TcpClient?), I don't seem to be able to find anything which feels like a "modern" way to do approach this, given what I've seen elsewhere in my C# adventures.

I suppose specifically I was expecting to see Tasks and code like `await socket.Connect(args)`, but instead I see callback-based async or BeginX methods...

What are my options, here? Do I just get on with it and work with something without TPL, or are there other approaches?

Many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12631467/745969).  You can also take a look at Stephen Toub's [Awaiting Socket Operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) article on his blog.

Comment: All these samples are terrible. Never use sockets with the APM pattern now that await exists! Also, question whether you need to go async at all. Sync IO is simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no [TAP-based](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) raw socket API, no. I believe that the BCL team took a look at the [`Socket` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) - which already supports a complete synchronous API and *two* complete asynchronous APIs - and decided that adding a third complete asynchronous API would just be too much.

It's easy enough to [use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to wrap the existing `Begin`/`End` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#ApmToTap). Personally, I like to do this with extension methods so they can be called more naturally.

But first you should take a step back and see if there's *any* way to avoid using raw sockets. In particular, see if SignalR is a possibility. Writing correct raw socket code is *extremely* difficult, and using a higher-level abstraction would be much easier.

Comment: But not half as fun! This isn't anything mission critical - I'd really like to be somebody who *can* write tricky socket code so I figure it's a nice little project. Thanks for your tips here - and also for the help you haven't so directly given me with your various other writings online!

Comment: @ledneb: In that case, I have a [TCP/IP FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) that may help you along. Good luck!

Comment: I hadn't come across that, looks a really useful read. Thanks again Stephen :-)