# .NET Core WinService Async Socket Listener

Tags: .net, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I currently am working on a high volume use case depending on socket connections. I have followed this article thus far which has got at least something working but I don't believe it will perform as needed for my use case thus why I am here looking for advise on how to optimize it properly.
[Using .Net 4.5 Async Feature for Socket Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630827/using-net-4-5-async-feature-for-socket-programming)

The solution provided does handle multiple clients connecting which in my use case will be exactly 12 clients. These clients will produce daily about 80,000 messages each so leveraging async is a must. What I currently am experiencing is that when I flush multiple messages, the service begins to lag and ultimately "stops" processing incoming messages. I think part of this is the TCP Client being created and destroyed over and over again. Is there a way I can permanently create the TCP Listener for each client and maintain a connection? I think with the volume of my use case, this overhead being removed will have a dramatic impact on performance. If you have other suggestions I am all ears for that also. One last thing about this solution I am using as a guide is there is a 60 second timer on the server thread which I didn't quite understand it's purpose. Feel free to ask questions! FYI, my implementation is the same as the article I linked earlier, just some logic change inside calling my service classes etc. which is all async Task in case you're wondering. :)

Answer (score 0):

In that demo, the 60 second timer is just something to STOP the listener after 60 seconds. In your use case, the listener should stay alive for as long as your server is running.

Comment: interesting, i definitely do not want that! lol